# Type enum does not conform to protocol 'CollectionType'

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I created such enum:

```
enum AudioCodecsType: String {
    case MPEG4AAC = "MPEG-4 Audio", iLBC = "iLBC"

    static let names = [
        MPEG4AAC : "MPEG 4 Audio", iLBC : "iLBC"]
}
```

Later I want to get values from its `names` dictionary:

```
var audioCodecs = AudioCodecsType.names.values as [String]
```

but I get compiler error: `Type 'AudioCodecsType.Type' does not conform to protocol 'CollectionType'`

How can I extract values from that dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values` property of a dictionary returns a lazy collection, which can be used for instance in loops. If want a traditional array, use its `array` property:

```
var audioCodecs = AudioCodecsType.names.values.array
```

Side note: you can redefine your `names` property as:

```
static let names = [
    MPEG4AAC : MPEG4AAC.rawValue,
    iLBC : iLBC.rawValue
]
```

less prone to typing errors :)